# Why does document.write() always cause the browsers tab to show the loading... indicator?

Tags: javascript

I have nothing on a page except the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function() {

   document.write('foo');

});

<script>
```

When I run this page in firefox the loading indicator in the current browser tab seems to be in perpetual motion, never stopping. Why does this happen? Is it indicating that the document.write script runs ceaselessly?

Comment: On Firefox 6 no problems for http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/c3k3X/.

Comment: @Sam: Is the HTML valid?

Comment: I would say that suggests that the connection between the server and the browser is still open - could be a server-side config issue - how are you serving the file? As a static `.html` file or dynamicly with e.g. PHP?

Comment: You haven't close your second `script` element... does fixing that solve the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to close the document after you've written to it:

```
document.write('foo');
document.close();
```

Otherwise the browser still has the document in an "open-for-writing" state, hence the loading indicator.

(Also, as @DaveRandom points out in his comment, you need close your `<script>` properly with `</script>`.)

Comment: ...and I also just realised that same `<script>` block is missing a `type="text/javascript"` attribute. I can confirm you solution fixes the problem for me in FF3/win32 :-)